# Package Implementation methdology

Tags: installation, configuration, migration

Basically, interested to learn on the suggested phased approach to have typic CiviCRM functionality adopted by an organization.  Is there any recommendation available on deployment plans in terms of major actions and resources needed out of any given organization ?  Thank you.

Comment: Others may have a better idea on how to answer this than I do. The organisations that we work with are so different and their needs are so specific that there is no 'typical'. Some only use for fundraising. Some have no fundraising needs. Others are all Cases and Activities.